# How to ensure minimum operation duration

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm building an Angular Material `mat-tree` with dynamic data (based on [this example](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples#tree-dynamic)).
When the user expend a node, a progress-bar is shown while the list of child nodes is retrieved from the server.

The base code looks like this:

```
toggleNode(node: DynamicFlatNode, expand: boolean) {
  if (expand) {
    // Shows progress bar
    node.isLoading = true;

    this
      .database
      .getChildren(node.id)
      .subscribe(
        values => {
          // Create and add the descendant nodes
          ...
        },
        error => { console.error(error); },
        () => {
          // Hides progress bar
          node.isLoading = false;
        });

  } else {
    // Remove descendant nodes
    ...
  }
}
```

The issue is that if the data retrieving is too quick, the progress bar just blink.
I would like to add a delay so the progress bar is shown at least, let say, 250ms.
I want the time of visibility to be `min(250ms, data retrieving time)` not `250 ms + data retrieving time`.

My current solution is to use a dummy promise, that starts before data retrieving and is awaited in the `complete` callback:

```
toggleNode(node: DynamicFlatNode, expand: boolean) {
  if (expand) {
    // Shows progress bar
    node.isLoading = true;

    const delay = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 250));
    this
      .database
      .getChildren(node.id)
      .subscribe(
        values => {
          // Create and add the descendant nodes
          ...
        },
        error => { console.error(error); },
        async () => {
          await delay;
          // Hides progress bar
          node.isLoading = false;
        });

  } else {
    // Remove descendant nodes
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there a more concise way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage the RxJS `timer` with `forkJoin` to introduce an artificial delay. I'd also suggest using the `finalize` operator to set the `isLoading` flag. If not you'd have to set it in both `error` and `complete` callbacks of the subscription.

Important: `forkJoin` will only emit when all it's source observables complete. So you need to make sure your observable `this.database.getChildren(node.id)` completes. If it doesn't you could force it to complete after the first emission using `take(1)`, assuming you wouldn't need the emission stream.

Try the following

```js
import { forkJoin, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize, map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

const DELAY = 250;

toggleNode(node: DynamicFlatNode, expand: boolean) {
  if (expand) {
    node.isLoading = true;                            // <-- show progress bar
    forkJoin({
      timer: timer(DELAY),
      children: this.database.getChildren(node.id),
    }).pipe(
      map(({ children }) => children),                // <-- ignore the `timer` emission
      finalize(() => (node.isLoading = false))        // <-- hide progress bar
    ).subscribe({
      next: (values: any) => {
        // create and add the descendant nodes
      },
      error: (error: any) => {
        // handle error
      },
    });
  } else {
    // remove descendant nodes
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6rcxlp?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Play with the `DELAY` variable to observe the induced delay.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab idea from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-a2gluv?file=index.ts)

```
import { of, map, Observable, combineLatest, delay, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { mapTo, startWith, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const GET_DATA_DELAY = 100;
const PROGRESS_DELAY = 250;
const getData = (): Observable<any> => {
  return of('data').pipe(delay(GET_DATA_DELAY));
};
const log = {
  next: (value: any) => console.log(`Date:${ (new Date()).toISOString()} : `, value),
  error: (err: any) => console.error(err),
};
const delay$ = timer(PROGRESS_DELAY).pipe(mapTo('timer'),tap(log));
const data$ = getData().pipe(tap(log));
const isLoading$ = combineLatest([delay$, data$]).pipe(
  mapTo(false),
  startWith(true),
  map(value => `IsLoading: ${value}`),
);
isLoading$.subscribe(log);

// Open the console in the bottom right to see results.
```